# Query to find list of tables and columns used in a sybase stored procedure

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I can get the table names with sp_depends  but how to get the column names used in a procedure.

Comment: there may be a way by looking at the code of the SP sp_depends (in db sybsystemprocs) or by exploring the content of the table sysdepends.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that information through supported SQL functionality. When you start looking into query processing diagnostics (e.g. dumping out internal query trees etc.) then this information could in principle be found. But this requires an understanding of the internal diagnostic info, which is very complex and not documented. You can certainly try to figure it out, and it may not be impossible, but you're on your own.